How to update dataframe rows based on a list in one of the columns of another dataframe
I have 2 dataframes:
# df1
   0  1  2 ECID
0  0  0  0   00
1  0  0  0   01
2  0  0  0   02

# df2
  ECID FailPattern
0   00      [1, 2]
1   01         [1]
2   02         [0]

Now I would like to use the FailPattern column in 2nd dataframe and update the first dataframe to have "1" on the numbers mentioned.
Ex: Fail pattern column has [1,2] in the 2nd dataframe , so I need to have 1.0 for both column "1" and and column "2" of first row which has ECID "00".
Ultimately, I want the dataframe to look like this
   0  1  2 ECID
0  0  1  1   00
1  0  1  0   01
2  1  0  0   02

How can i do this using pandas?

why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

I see two options.
The first one would be to melt and merge, then reshape back to the original form with pivot/reindex:
out = (df1
  .reset_index().melt(['index', 'ECID'], var_name='FailPattern')
  .merge(df2.explode('FailPattern').assign(value2=1), how='left')
  .assign(value=lambda d: d['value2'].fillna(d['value']))
  .pivot(index=['index', 'ECID'], columns='FailPattern', values='value')
  .reset_index('ECID').reindex_like(df1)
)

Output:
     0    1    2 ECID
0  0.0  1.0  1.0   00
1  0.0  1.0  0.0   01
2  1.0  0.0  0.0   02

Another option would be to use numpy to create a mask to assign the 1s in place:
# create mappers for ECID and columns
col_n, cols = pd.factorize(df1.columns)
idx_n, idx = pd.factorize(df1['ECID'])

# convert the FailPattern lists to rows
tmp = df2.explode('FailPattern')

# create array of False to serve as mask
# and set up True on indices to replace with 1
mask = np.zeros_like(df1, dtype=bool)
mask[tmp['ECID'].map(dict(zip(idx, idx_n))),
     tmp['FailPattern'].map(dict(zip(cols, col_n)))
    ] = True

# use the mask to modify the DataFrame in place
df1[mask] = 1

Modified df1:
   0  1  2 ECID
0  0  1  1   00
1  0  1  0   01
2  1  0  0   02

Reproducible inputs:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 'ECID': ['00', '01', '02']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ECID': ['00', '01', '02'],
                    'FailPattern': [[1, 2], [1], [0]]})

Intermediates (melt+merge):
(df1
  .reset_index().melt(['index', 'ECID'], var_name='FailPattern')
  .merge(df2.explode('FailPattern').assign(value2=1), how='left')
)

#    index ECID FailPattern  value  value2
# 0      0   00           0      0     NaN
# 1      1   01           0      0     NaN
# 2      2   02           0      0     1.0
# 3      0   00           1      0     1.0
# 4      1   01           1      0     1.0
# 5      2   02           1      0     NaN
# 6      0   00           2      0     1.0
# 7      1   01           2      0     NaN
# 8      2   02           2      0     NaN

Intermediates (numpy approach):
tmp
#   ECID FailPattern
# 0   00           1
# 0   00           2
# 1   01           1
# 2   02           0

tmp['ECID'].map(dict(zip(idx, idx_n)))
# [0, 0, 1, 2]

tmp['FailPattern'].map(dict(zip(cols, col_n)))
# [1, 2, 1, 0]

mask
# array([[False,  True,  True, False],
#        [False,  True, False, False],
#        [ True, False, False, False]])


I like the numpy approach as its much faster, thanks for the help :)

@Nandeep yes that's why I added it, using numpy is usually more efficient ;)

you can use .at for using and updating cell value
example code(if "FailPattern" dtype is string):
for i in range(len(df1)):
  if "0" in df2.at[i,"FailPattern"]:
    df1.at[i, "0"] = 1.0
  if "1" in df2.at[i,"FailPattern"]:
    df1.at[i, "1"] = 1.0
  if "2" in df2.at[i,"FailPattern"]:
    df1.at[i, "2"] = 1.0

example code(if "FailPattern" dtype is list):
for i in range(len(df1)):
  if 0 in df2.at[i,"FailPattern"]:
    df1.at[i, "0"] = 1.0
  if 1 in df2.at[i,"FailPattern"]:
    df1.at[i, "1"] = 1.0
  if 2 in df2.at[i,"FailPattern"]:
    df1.at[i, "2"] = 1.0


There is probably a better way to do this, but this seems to work:
def fail_pattern(row):
  print(type(row))
  # find corresponding row in df2
  try:
    # find matching row
    cmp_row = df2[df2["ECID"]==row["ECID"]]

    # should only have one result
    if cmp_row.shape[0] != 1:
      return row
    
    # get fail pattern and convert
    fpat = cmp_row["FailPattern"].tolist()
    for p in fpat:
      row[p] = 1.0
    return row
  except:
    return row

Then to apply:
df1 = df1.apply(fail_pattern, axis=1)

Here's a Colab notebook with an example of this working: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bFnfMarU_ODlee5znA1g_7jB_Q7kiUgC?usp=sharing

One option is to use pd.get_dummies() with combine_first()
(pd.get_dummies(
    df2.set_index('ECID')['FailPattern'].explode()
    )
.groupby(level=0).sum()
.combine_first(
    df1.set_index('ECID')
    )
    .reset_index()
)

Output:
  ECID  0  1  2
0   00  0  1  1
1   01  0  1  0
2   02  1  0  0

